# Help required with the phrasing of Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My hypothesis states that "there would be a significant correlation between A and B".
Where A has 3 sub-variables/ dimensions- m, n and o.
Now the results show a significant relationship of dimension m and n with B but a non-significant relationship between o and B.

So in discussion of the results, What phrase should I use?
I was thinking to use the phrase- "the hypothesis was partially accepted". But I think its incorrect. So, What should I write instead?

Comment: If you did 3 tests then you have three hypotheses, not one. In which case you present which hypotheses you rejected and which you kept.

Comment: Welcome to CV. "Significant correlation between A and B" is not a valid hypothesis, because hypotheses make statements about *the real world* (or, more accurately, about a probability model of part of the world), whereas "significance" is a statement about *data.*  What exactly is a "subvariable" or "dimension"?  What specific role did these "dimensions" play in your testing?

Comment: user2974951 I know I could have had 3 different hypotheses, but this is just an example. In real life, there are multiple independent variables with multiple dimensions. Say if I have 10 dimensions of one variable which I wish to study, Will I have to have 10 separate hypotheses.

Comment: user2974951 Continued** Let me rephrase my question, Can a hypothesis include multiple dimensions? and if so, what statement must I write as hypothesis result if few of those variables are significant and others are not? Is the "null hypothesis is rejected" a correct statement?

Comment: Whuber Hello, I am talking about psychological research, It's experimental research so I am talking about data only.

Comment: You cannot have a hypotheses composed of different subhypotheses. If you divide your variable into 10 parts then you will run 10 tests with 10 different hypotheses for the 10 subsets. You cannot generate a "global" hypothesis from the variable subsets, you need a new hypotheses / test for the whole variable.

Comment: user2974951 Ok thanks for the help.